# how to check if asyncio loop has any associated sockets

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

asyncio.Task.all_tasks() gives a list of all tasks for an event loop, but I can't find anything similar for sockets, and in particular, datagram sockets associated with a loop?

The absence of sockets & tasks could then signal "end of life" for the loop.

The question is, in the following example, what to put in `loop_not_empty()` that makes it return `False` when the task set is empty **and** there are no associated sockets (ie after two seconds)

Example:

```
import asyncio
import socket
import threading

class Handler(asyncio.Protocol):
    def connection_made(self, transport):
        self.transport = transport
        print("connection made")

    def datagram_received(self, data, addr):
        if data == b'die':
            print("shutting down")
            self.transport.abort()

@asyncio.coroutine
def sometask():
    yield from asyncio.sleep(1)
    print("task done")

def loop_not_empty(l):
    # if asyncio.Task.all_tasks() == set() and WHAT_GOES_HERE
    #   return False
    return True

def main():
    a,b = socket.socketpair(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

    l = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    asyncio.ensure_future(sometask(), loop=l)
    asyncio.ensure_future(l.create_datagram_endpoint(Handler, sock=a), loop=l)

    threading.Timer(2, lambda: b.send(b'die')).start()

    while loop_not_empty(l):
        l.run_until_complete(asyncio.sleep(1, loop=l))

main()
```

Comment: This is unclear. Please supply a piece of code, where you expect this "end of life" check to be executed.

Comment: Trying to clarify with an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution that uses a simple class and `asyncio.Event()` to count the number of active jobs and signals the loop to stop when all jobs are done:

```
import asyncio

import random


class UseCounter:
    def __init__(self, loop=None):
        self.loop = loop
        self.event = asyncio.Event(loop=loop)
        self.n = 0  # The number of active jobs

    def __enter__(self):
        self.enter()

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        self.exit()

    def enter(self):
        self.n += 1

    def exit(self):
        self.n -= 1
        if self.n == 0:
            self.event.set()

    async def wait(self):
        return await self.event.wait()


async def my_coroutine(counter, term):
    with counter:
        print("start", term)
        n = random.uniform(0.2, 1.5)
        await asyncio.sleep(n)
        print("end", term)


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
counter = UseCounter(loop)
terms = ["apple", "banana", "melon"]
for term in terms:
    asyncio.ensure_future(my_coroutine(counter, term))

loop.run_until_complete(counter.wait())

loop.close()
```

For your example above, add `.enter()` to `connection_made()` and `.exit()` to `connection_lost()`.

Comment: Interesting. That's basically ref-counting the event loop. It does solve the problem, but "intrusive" in that all tasks and sockets need to remember to do the ref-count dance. I'll leave it open for a couple of days, hoping for a neater solution.